# group_by 後に count した時、必要なカラムのみ表示したい

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

下記のように、`seaborn`でデフォルトで読み込める tips のデータで試してみました。

`total_bill`や`tip`とそれに続くカラムは全て同じカウントの数を出しているだけなので不要です。
`count`というカラムだけあればいいと思うのですが、どのようにすれば実現できますか？

**試したコード:**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling as pdp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
    
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.groupby('day').count()
```

**結果:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 戻り値は `Series` 型になりますが `tips.groupby('day')['day'].count()` か `tips.groupby('day').size()` か `tips.value_counts(subset=['day'])` などでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家SOでいくつか書き方を見つけました。

`reset_index`[例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48770057)

```
tips.groupby('day').day.count().to_frame('count').reset_index()
""" 
    day  count
0  Thur     62
1   Fri     19
2   Sat     87
3   Sun     76
"""
```

`agg`[例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836715)

```
tips.groupby('day').agg(count = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'day', aggfunc = 'count'))
""" 
      count
day
Thur     62
Fri      19
Sat      87
Sun      76
"""
```

カラムを絞る[例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417351)

```
tips.groupby('day')['total_bill'].count()
""" 
day
Thur    62
Fri     19
Sat     87
Sun     76
Name: total_bill, dtype: int64
"""
```